# How to know a link flag from a framework?

Tags: c++, c, flash

For example, I have SDL2/Include and SDL2/lib in my computer
How to know what link flags options that will be use by the compiler fir linking options ? How to know it is -lSDL2main ?

Comment: By reading the framework documentation.

Comment: is there a command for ?

Comment: For what, exactly?

Comment: To know the -flag option from a dylib file

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the word "documentation"?

Comment: No, as latedeveloper said you read the documentation to know which libs you need to link against, and you read your compiler's documentation to know what flag is used for specifying libs (in this case -l$(lib_name))

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on what compiler you use. You'll find the answer in the manual of that compiler.

Here is an excerpt of one particular compilers [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

> -l library
>
> ... The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>
> ...     The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several directories.

The documentation fails to mention, that '.so' extended filenames are also considered.

So, if this is the compiler that you are using, and if the file that you intend to link with is called `libSDL2main.a`, then you'll know that you'll need to specify `-lSDL2main` to the link command.

---

A framework may provide multiple archive files. The documentation of the framework should tell you which of those files you should link with.